# Calculate number of training parameters using Neural Network Toolbox

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning

I have built a CNN using the Matlab Neural Network Toolbox. How can I calculate the total number of parameters used in my network?

For example, I can use the analyzeNetwork() from the support addon, and this can show me the number of learnable parameters per layer. Would it be correct to add these up?

```
layers = [
imageInputLayer([128 300 1])

convolution2dLayer([7 7], 32, 'Stride', [2 2], 'Padding', 1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer

convolution2dLayer([5 5], 32, 'Stride', [2 2], 'Padding', 1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer

convolution2dLayer([3 3], 64, 'Stride', [2 2],'Padding', 1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer
dropoutLayer(0.2)

convolution2dLayer([3 3], 64, 'Stride', [2 2],'Padding', 1)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer
dropoutLayer(0.2)

convolution2dLayer([8 1], 1024, 'Stride', [1 1],'Padding', 0)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer
dropoutLayer(0.2)

averagePooling2dLayer([1 12],'Stride', [1 1]);
dropoutLayer(0.2)

fullyConnectedLayer(4096)
batchNormalizationLayer
reluLayer

dropoutLayer(0.2)

fullyConnectedLayer(1251)
softmaxLayer
classificationLayer];
```

Comment: What are `imageSize` and `numClasses`? Please add this to your question.

Comment: imageSize is 128x300x1 and numClasses are 1251

Comment: The network analyzer shows that ReLU layers have 0 learnable parameters. This means it cannot be trusted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `analyzeNetwork()` from the support addon, and added up all of the learnable parameters, equalling 1.4M.

I then created the same network in matconvnet library, and used `vl_simplenn_display` to analyse the network. It also showed 1.4M parameters.